# How do I return to my Windows Phone app from a YouTube video?

Tags: windows-phone-7, youtube

I have a Windows Phone 7 app that launches a YouTube video. It does this by creating a WebBrowserTask and setting it's url to "vnd.youtube:" + id. This opens a new web browser which, then, launches the YouTube application.

Once they've seen the video, the user should be able to click the "Back" button to return to the application. However, when they click "back" it just returns them to the WebBrowserTask which then re-launches the video.

Does anyone know a way I can get them back to the app?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to do this using a webbrowser control embedded in one of your Xaml pages. This would allow you to detect the back operation and to navigate within your app accordingly.

Comment: I would MUCH rather do that if you know how I can? As far as I can tell, you can't launch an external app (e.g., the YouTube player) from the embedded web browser control.